# Running a python app on AWS with fabric

Tags: fabric

I'm trying to run a python web app on AWS. It works fine if I log into AWS with SSH. But with fabric this does not work. I tried:

```
run('python app.py &')
```

And:

```
sudo('python app.py &')
```

No repsonse:

```
$ python awsstart.py run
[ec2-user@XYZ] run: python app.py &
$ (empty)
```

Comment: Did other remote commands work (ls, etc.)?

Comment: yes. everything works. sudo and starting the app within ssh.

Comment: And does also work a `ls` with *fabric*?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you don't see any result/response because of "&" sign at the end of your commands? It seems that it is working but you don't see any output since it is working at background.

Can you try the following?

```
sudo("python app.py")
```